# Correct syntax for a multi line comment in xml?

Tags: xml, comments

Can i write a multi line comment in an xml file as follows ? I some text editors it displays it as greyed out (as it should for a comment) and in other text editors ive tried it in it colours the multi line text in white showing it dosnt know what it is ?

If this isnt the correct syntax for a multi line comment, what is ?

```
<!--CUSTOM BLOCK START-->
<!--
    Have set : 
    - command 1 fires (no response required)
    - wait 3000ms
    - command 1 repeat fires 
-->
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is the correct syntax.

Blame poor syntax highlighters of some of your editors.